# How to make alerts fade out in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap alerts,i tried multiple ways to make them fade out but it didn't work.
This is the code:

```
<div class='col-sm-7 alert alert-success' id='alrt' role='alert'>
<i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i>
<b>Etudiant ajouté avec succés</b>
</div>
```

the alert show up automatically when opening the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643308/how-to-automatically-close-alerts-using-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676356/can-twitter-bootstrap-alerts-fade-in-as-well-as-out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138967/bootstrap-3-how-to-fade-in-alert-box-on-click-and-fade-out-after-3-seconds

Answer (score 5):

you can add '.in' class, alert fade out.

```
<div class="alert alert-info fade in">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#"></a>
<p>message inside alert goes here</p>
</div>
```